# How to import addTableModelListener() in Java

Tags: java

I am a beginner.
I want to use `addTableModelListener` in the followinc code, but I am not sure how to import in .Java file. I am not sure but it whould be something like `import javax.swing.table;`

```
tableModel.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent tableModelEvent) {
        if(table.isEditing())
        String value = table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),3);    
        //do stuff  with value          
    }
});
```

Comment: If you don't know how to use `import`, then you might consider taking a step back first, as you're digging yourself into a very large hole.  See [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details about how to use `JTable`.  As a hint, the `TableModel` (and by association, it's listener) shouldn't care about the `JTable`, as you have no means to be sure that the model is been used in the instance of `JTable` you're checking

Comment: Read the API for the TableModelListener. It will tell you the package to import. You can't program if you don't have access to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can import `addTableModelListener`  as below:

```
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
```

For example, refer to the following link:

[Reference Link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing.table/TableModeladdTableModelListenerTableModelListenerl.htm)